# React Typescript: How run some lines at the same time as each other, and other parts need to wait

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't want to wait for section1 to complete before starting section 2 and then wait for section 2 before doing section 3, all the 3 sections can run at the same time.

```
  const uploadImages = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const signedUrlApiEndpoint = `${global.env.apiUrl}/upload/signed-url`;
    const apiEndpoint = `${global.env.apiUrl}/my/add-photo`;
    let thumbnailId;
    let previewId;
    let zoomId;
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: true }));

// Section 1 - can run at the same time as sections 2 and 3
// --------------------------------------------------------
    const thumbnailSignedUrl = await SignedUrl(signedUrlApiEndpoint);
    const resizedThumbnail = await ResizeImage(originalImage, 180, positionId);
    if (thumbnailSignedUrl && resizedThumbnail) {
      thumbnailId = await UploadToS3(thumbnailSignedUrl, resizedThumbnail);
    } else alert('s3 error');

// Section 2 - can run at the same time as sections 1 and 3
// --------------------------------------------------------
    const previewSignedUrl = await SignedUrl(signedUrlApiEndpoint);
    const resizedPreview = await ResizeImage(originalImage, 530, positionId);
    if (previewSignedUrl && resizedPreview) {
      previewId = await UploadToS3(previewSignedUrl, resizedPreview);
    } else alert('s3 error');

// Section 3 - can run at the same time as sections 1 and 2
// --------------------------------------------------------
    const zoomSignedUrl = await SignedUrl(signedUrlApiEndpoint);
    const resizedZoom = await ResizeImage(originalImage, 1000, positionId);
    if (zoomSignedUrl && resizedZoom) {
      zoomId = await UploadToS3(zoomSignedUrl, resizedZoom);
    } else alert('s3 error');
```

Here I need all the data from section 1,2 and 3

```
// ----
    if (thumbnailId && previewId && zoomId) {
      const imagesSaved = await SaveImage(
        apiEndpoint,
        category,
        previewId,
        thumbnailId,
        zoomId
      );
      if (imagesSaved) {
        setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: false }));
        dispatch({ type: SET_MODAL, value: '' });
      }
    } else alert('err');
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :)

```
const uploadImages = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const signedUrlApiEndpoint = `${global.env.apiUrl}/upload/signed-url`;
  const apiEndpoint = `${global.env.apiUrl}/my/add-photo`;
  let thumbnailId;
  let previewId;
  let zoomId;
  setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: true }));

  async function section1 () {
    const [thumbnailSignedUrl, resizedThumbnail]  = await Promise.all([SignedUrl(signedUrlApiEndpoint),ResizeImage(originalImage, 180, positionId)]);
    if (thumbnailSignedUrl && resizedThumbnail) {
      return await UploadToS3(thumbnailSignedUrl, resizedThumbnail);
    } else {
      throw Error('s3 error')
    }
  }

  async function section2 () {
    const [previewSignedUrl, resizedPreview] = await Promise.all([SignedUrl(signedUrlApiEndpoint),ResizeImage(originalImage, 530, positionId)]);
    if (previewSignedUrl && resizedPreview) {
      return await UploadToS3(previewSignedUrl, resizedPreview);
    } else {
      throw Error('s3 error')
    }
  }

  async function section3 () {
    const [zoomSignedUrl, resizedZoom] = await Promise.all([SignedUrl(signedUrlApiEndpoint), ResizeImage(originalImage, 1000, positionId)]);
    if (zoomSignedUrl && resizedZoom) {
      return await UploadToS3(zoomSignedUrl, resizedZoom);
    } else {
      throw Error('s3 error')
    }
  }

  [thumbnailId, previewId, zoomId] = await Promise.all([section1(), section2(), section3()])
}
```

Comment: it looks good, but im getting the error `''section1' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.ts(7023)'` same for section2 and section3

Comment: I think the `promise.all` needs to be an array of functions?

Comment: and then i just have `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'thumbnailId'.ts(2451)` and same for previewId, zoomId

Comment: Almost there just `[thumbnailId, previewId, zoomId] = ...` is redeclare block-scoped variables

Comment: I removed their redeclaration. It should not throw that error anymore :)

Comment: `return await` can be just `return`

Comment: @Bill I doubt that. Read this https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/ :)